# Mockito mocking a new instance call with parameters

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

For school purposes I am creating an application that's working with a stock API.

I am trying to write a test for a method that gets all the stock data of the last 10 years. Instead of actually getting all that data, I want to throw an exception.

The method I Want to test:

```
@Override
public List<StockData> getAllTeslaStockData() throws AlphaVantageException {
    List<StockData> stockData;

    AlphaVantageConnector apiConnector = new AlphaVantageConnector(APIKEY, TIMEOUT);
    TimeSeries stockTimeSeries = new TimeSeries(apiConnector);

    try {

        Daily responseDaily = stockTimeSeries.daily("TSLA", OutputSize.FULL);
        stockData = responseDaily.getStockData();

    } catch (AlphaVantageException e) {

        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "something went wrong: ", e);

        throw e;

    }

    return stockData;
}
```

The stockTimeSeries.daily(....) call can throw the AlphaVantageException.

I've mocked the TimeSeries class like this:

```
TimeSeries stockTimeSeries = mock(TimeSeries.class);
```

In my test class I want to mock this call, and return an exception instead of actual data.

```
when(stockTimeSeries.daily("TSLA", OutputSize.FULL)).thenThrow(new AlphaVantageException("No stock data available"));
```

Regardless of how I am trying to mock this bit of code, it'll never throw the exception. It will always just execute the code, and return valid stock data, instead of throwing the exception like i've tried to do.

How can I mock this bit of code, so that itll throw the exception I am expecting for my tests.

The AlphaVantageConnector, TimeSeries and Daily classes are part of a library used to access the stock API, so I can't change these classes.

I am using JUnit 4.12 and Mockito to try and achieve this.

Comment: Have you mocked the creation of the instance itself (new TimeSeries(apiConnector);) and assigned it the mocked reference "stockTimeSeries " ? TimeSeries stockTimeSeries = new TimeSeries(apiConnector);

Comment: As far as I am aware, mockito doesn't allow the mocking of constructors, correct me if I am wrong @AnkurChrungoo

Comment: There are other ways of mocking a constructor if you want to. But, my question was more related to how are you expecting that Mockito will identify "stockTimeSeries" as being the mock reference which the method should use. The method is creating its own instance and using it, so everytime it will call the actual method instead of using the mock object.

Comment: One simple example is just to create a method (in your class) which returns you the TimeSeries object , and then Mock that method in your Junit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TimeSeries` object is created in the method itself, so you can't mock it - mocking is intended to mock members.

What you can do is to do something like

```
class YourClass {
   private Supplier<TimeSeries> seriesCreator = () -> {
       return new TimeSeries(new AlphaVantageConnector(APIKEY, TIMEOUT));
   }
```

which you use to create the series in your method

```
@Override
public List<StockData> getAllTeslaStockData() throws AlphaVantageException {
    TimeSeries stockTimeSeries = seriesCreator.get();
```

Now you can mock that `Supplier`.

```
@Mock Supplier<TimeSeries> seriesCreatorMock;
@InjectMocks MyClass sut;
```

and in your test

```
@Test(expected = AlphaVantageException.class)
void testException() {
    when(seriesCreatorMock.get()).thenThrow(new AlphaVantageException());
    sut.getAllTeslaStockData()
}
```

EDIT: as suggested by Angkur in the comments, the clean way would be to

```
class SeriesCreator implements Supplier<TimeSeries> {
    public TimeSeries get() {
       return new TimeSeries(new AlphaVantageConnector(APIKEY, TIMEOUT));
    }
}

class YourClass {
   private Supplier<TimeSeries> seriesCreator = new SeriesCreator();
```

// ...

Comment: Correct, but wouldn't it be much easier to create a simple method which returns the TimeSeries object, and mock it. The use of Supplier here seems to be a bit unnecessary.

Comment: @AnkurChrungoo Well if you created a method in the `MyClass` class that you want to test, you can't really mock it. You'd need to create a subclass for the test that overrides the method, and that's not really clean testing.

Comment: You should be able to mock it with .spy()

Comment: @AnkurChrungoo The point is either way you'd _change the class you're testing_.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I just wanted to say that Supplier is an advanced way of doing it, but simpler is also possible.

Comment: Just to add here, it may also be possible that the creation of TimeSeries object doesn't really belong to this class, but another, and if so, should be separated. In that case mocking would be much easier. But of course, we can't judge this based on the limited info available.

Comment: @AnkurChrungoo Yes, the creation of the TimeSeries object being done outside of this class is exactly the setup of my answer.

Comment: Ok, I thought you were embedding that in the same class.

Comment: I like this idea. But this idea creates the problem that if I do want to use the actual method, instead of the mocked one, then I can't. Get is abstact, and @Spy with thenCallRealMethed doesnt allow abstracts to be called. This provides an answer as how to Mock, which I am happy about. Thank you for that both daniu and Ankur. I will figure out how to do real calls myself.

Comment: @Jeroen I edited the answer to add the "proper" way Ankur was suggesting. This way you could also `@Spy` the creator class - however, note that is usually bad practice.

Comment: @daniu much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can use **thenThrow()** method. Below is the example

```html
@Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
public void whenConfigNonVoidRetunMethodToThrowEx_thenExIsThrown() {
    MyDictionary dictMock = mock(MyDictionary.class);
    when(dictMock.getMeaning(anyString()))
      .thenThrow(NullPointerException.class);
 
    dictMock.getMeaning("word");
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in the main class is creating a **new instance of TimeSeries** which it will use every time this method is called, so the mocked TimeSeries object is not getting used at all.

```
TimeSeries stockTimeSeries = new TimeSeries(apiConnector);  // --> This is not getting mocked

    try {

        Daily responseDaily = stockTimeSeries.daily("TSLA", OutputSize.FULL);
        stockData = responseDaily.getStockData();

    }
```

You should create another method in your class (or even a separate class if it better satisfies the SOLID principles) which returns you the TimeSeries object. Something like:-

```
<access modifier> TimeSeries getTimeSeries(...) {

}
```

and then this method should be mocked in the Junit, and when mocked, it should return the Mocked TimeSeries reference (which is created in `TimeSeries stockTimeSeries = mock(TimeSeries.class);` ). You would need to use `.spy()` on the main class (unless you are using a different class to create TimeSeries object) in order to be able to mock the specific method `getTimeSeries()` but not the others.

```
MainClass mainObject = Mockito.spy(new MainClass());
Mockito.when(mainObject.getTimeSeries()).thenReturn(stockTimeSeries);
```

Then, the method call `stockTimeSeries.daily()` will get actually mocked by your existing code :

```
when(stockTimeSeries.daily("TSLA", OutputSize.FULL)).thenThrow(new AlphaVantageException("No stock data available"));
```

NOTE: you should also consider using `.anyString()` style methods provided by Mockito API while mocking.